What is the "necessary existence", and what makes it "necessary"?
B"H
Often times regarding the first halacha of Yesodei Hatorah chapter 1, I hear from different people that the Rambam is discussing the concept of G-d as a "necessary existence" as opposed to the world as an "optional existence".
To elaborate on some questions I have about this idea:
The difficulty is that what is the necessary proof that if everything else would cease to exist, He alone would continue to exist (which is seemingly the simple meaning of "necessary existence")?
I would think necessary existence means that logically it's necessary it exists, which means it can be proven. It's the proof just that it's passed down that He's the necessary existence?
If so, he doesn't seem to give a source for that. (The verse anochi Hashem elokeicha that he brings doesn't seem to suggest this idea).
My current understanding of it, is that everything we see doesn't have to exist the way it exists now, and therefore doesn't have to exist at all.
However, when it comes to the state of "Nothing", there's only one way NOTHING can exist. "Nothing" can't NOT exist in a state of nothingness, because then it wouldn't be nothing. Therefore, "Nothing" is the real, necessary existence. And hashem in essence is what we would call "Nothing"--despite being the true "something", therefore, He is the necessary existence
Is this accurate? If not, then what is the explanation for what the necessary existence is, and how we know it's necessary?

Not commentaries on the MT so just a comment. This is discussed in Sefer HaIkkarim 2. See also Derech Mitzvotecha He'Emanut Elokut sec. 1 and 11.

@RabbiKaii thanks looks interesting

What is meant by the necessary existence of x is the absence of external cause for x. Accordingly the Rambam states that if all entities in the universe ceased to exist, God would continue to exist... He is "self-caused", He exists of necessity. The rest of creation is contingent existence, it does not exist of necessity. Which aspect are you having difficulty understanding?

See More Nevuchim 1:69 and part 2 introduction (19-20) and chapter 1 (third way)

@Deuteronomy the difficulty is that what is the necessary proof that that is true,? I would think necessary existence means that logically it's necessary it exists, which means it can be proven. It's the proof just that it's passed down that He's the necessary existence? If so, he doesn't seem to give a source for that. (The verse anochi Hashem elokeicha that he brings doesn't seem to suggest this idea)

Without your most recent edits, it was hard to understand that you are looking for proof  of the concept of "necessary existence" as found in the Rambam. Thanks for clarifying your intent.

@Deuteronomy not necessarily, also WHAT it is should be part of the answer. Please do NOT edit the title

No problem, I thought I was bringing it in line with your expressed intention. As of now it seems like you either have multiple significant questions meriting individual responses (and therefore should be splitting this up) or that you aren't quite clear on what you are trying to ask (or at least not expressing it in a way that it could be readily understood by others). I hope that you can edit to resolve these issues so that we can best try to assist you.

Where's the question here? Who says that there has to be a proof to the idea that necessary existence refers to G-d? If there doesn't have to be a proof, then all motivation for your spinnings falls away. Further, why suggest that what the Rambam meant by necessary existence is some logical necessity, especially if you end up having to explain it as referring to G-d anyways? Where is the motivation to explain that "necessary" means only one form of being? How could it possibly be that what he meant by "necessary existence" was "nothing", when nothing is by definition not an existence?

This could also use some editing for clarity. Take another look at what you wrote to reorganize your thoughts, it might also help you make progress on the topic.

Rabbi Tauber's commentary on Derech Mitzvotecha:

Every other being was created; brought into existence from utter nothingness. In other words, the truth of every other entity's existence is non-being. Since there was a time when it did not exist, even now when it does exist, its fundamental state is non-being. Although it can exist, there is no necessity that it exists. Instead, it exists only because G-d wills that it be.
G-d's existence, by contrast, has no reason and no motivating rationale. He just is. And He always was and always will be. The very definition of Him as G-d implies that He was not brought into being at any time or by any other cause. Instead He exists independently. He must be, for He is the truth of existence. This is implied by the term mechuyav hametzius.

As R Albo states in Sefer HaIkkarim, His existence must be. His existence is from Himself, and is not the result of any other cause which preceded it.
The proof of this is therefore the logic of the matter, and this is also a teaching of our tradition: As we know, Avraham Avinu discovered Hashem through a process of logical deduction, and coming up with the definition of Hashem's existence that He is definitionally the ultimate power and source of everything else (brought in MT AZ 1:3, see Maaseh Rokeach on OP's halacha: MT Y'HT 1:1).
As for Rambam's source, Migdal Oz writes on this halacha:

כתב רבינו משה ז"ל יסוד היסודות וכו' עד בלא יד ובלא גוף. זה מקבלתו
וחכמתו ואמתת אמונתו ואמונתנו וכללו במצות אנכי ה' אלקיך:
Our teacher Moshe [Rambam] wrote [this halacha] 'The foundation of
foundations' etc. until 'with not a hand nor a body'. This was what he
received, understood, and is his true faith, and our faith, and is
included under the mitzva "I am Hashem your God".

Derech Mitzvotecha makes a strong case that the Mitzva of knowing and believing in Hashem means not knowing and believing that He exists, but deeply understanding this very point, and as such getting to know Him. Without that, it is impossible to feel anything when serving Hashem, and we might end up like the theif who davens to Hashem for success, ch'v (HaEmunat Elokut 1-3).

But why is there a difference between Hashem and creation in terms of needing to exist

@Awtsmoos--עצמות if Hashem stopped creating you, could you continue to create yourself into existence? If not, the reason why not is the answer to your question

Hi. The question is why did and does Hashem need to exist logically

@Awtsmoos--עצמות sorry, I don't follow the question. He exists because of Him, nothing/nobody else. Where in that are you asking why?

I mean the idea of a necessary existence should consist of a definition that explains how and why it is necessary. I can also just say "this chair" is a necessary existence", but what actually makes it necessary, other than saying it is?

@Awtsmoos--עצמות why it is necessary is because we see that the world exists, and is unnecessary, so we know there is a necessary, "true" (Rambam) existence. How- because Hashem can do that. We can't understand the how beyond that, as it's a bit like saying "Hashem created Himself", which obviously is not something our brains are able to imagine. The truth is, mechuyav/muchrach hametzius is not the highest level, metzius meAtzmuso is, and on that level, even "existence" is seen as a creation, and is not "necessary"... but that's beyond the scope of this question...

Note, you can't just say the chair is a necessary existence because you know for a fact it didn't exist 100 years ago, and won't exist in 100 years. If you think deeply about it, and study science, everything is like that. You don't know any existence that is truely true, that is real, it doesn't have a previous cause, it always was, and will be, in this world. So, unnecessary existence is all you know. Rambam is asserting as a mitzva, that you should know that Hashem is not like that, because He is the reality and foundation of all other realities.

But how does the Rambam himself know that

כתב  רבינו משה ז"ל  יסוד היסודות וכו' עד בלא יד ובלא גוף.  זה מקבלתו וחכמתו ואמתת אמונתו ואמונתנו וכללו במצות אנכי ה' אלהיך: @Awtsmoos--עצמות

Hi @EthanLeonard, been a while since I heard from you, nice surprise. Are both of your comments directed at me? To be honest, the only part I properly understood was "reorganise", but everything else is ambiguous. Feel free to explain again

You may also edit my answer, I think you know how to make it better and more developed

@RabbiKaii I meant to post both of those as comments to the question. Your answer was perfectly coherent. My mistake.
